# Where does console.log go by default?

Tags: javascript

If I don't install firebug or its equivalent in other browsers, where do javascript console.log statements go?

How is it that the language has this built in function if there's no built-in place for the output?

The ideal answer gives some insight into how console.log works-- what the console object is and what it's doing DOM-wise or elsewise to find a place for output.

Comment: It's just ignored. The environments will initialise it with empty functions for compatibility (not in IE unfortunately) and if there's a debugger activated it will "overwrite" them to receive the arguments (and display them in a custom way, for example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `console` object is not part of the language. It is supported by browsers natively (like Chrome and newer Firefox versions) or added by plugins (like Firebug).

There is no "default" behaviour. If you want to know how `console` could be implemented manually, have a look at [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).